# framework7 init not firing on page init

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, html-framework-7

Init not working in framework 7
I have tried all solution given in the below link
[framework7 Page Init Event Not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471191/framework7-page-init-event-not-firing)

```
// Initialize Application
var myApp = new Framework7({    
    animateNavBackIcon: true,
    // Enable templates auto precompilation
    precompileTemplates: true,
    // Enabled pages rendering using Template7
    swipeBackPage: false,
    swipeBackPageThreshold: 1,
    swipePanel: "left",
    swipePanelCloseOpposite: true,
    pushState: true,
    pushStateRoot: undefined,
    pushStateNoAnimation: false,
    pushStateSeparator: '#!/',
    template7Pages: true
});

// Export selectors engine
var $ = Dom7;

// Add main View
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
    // Enable dynamic Navbar
    dynamicNavbar: false
});

$(document).on('page:init', function (e) {
    console.log("Please Run");
});

myApp.init();
```

Comment: what about using this inside `new Framework7({ ...  }}`: `on: {
      pageInit: function (page) {
        alert('code is work...');
      },
  },` or this `app.on('pageInit', function (page) {
    alert('code is work');
});`...also, make sure plz theres no error in console too.

Comment: tried both it's not working .. 2nd example give error app or myApp is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add init false

```
var myApp = new Framework7({    
    animateNavBackIcon: true,
    // Enable templates auto precompilation
    precompileTemplates: true,
    // Enabled pages rendering using Template7
    swipeBackPage: false,
    swipeBackPageThreshold: 1,
    swipePanel: "left",
    swipePanelCloseOpposite: true,
    pushState: true,
    pushStateRoot: undefined,
    pushStateNoAnimation: false,
    pushStateSeparator: '#!/',
    template7Pages: true,
    init:false
});
```

Then initialize manually

```
// Export selectors engine
var $ = Dom7;

// Add main View
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
    // Enable dynamic Navbar
    dynamicNavbar: false
});

$(document).on('page:init', function (e) {
    console.log("Please Run");
});

myApp.init();
```

Which version of framework you are using